# can't execute shell script from crontab

Tags: cron

can't execute shell script from crontab

Here is my crontab

```
* * * * *       /home/open-cv/run.sh
```

Here is my run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/py
source env/bin/activate
python script.py
```

Comment: Redirect output/errors to a log so you can see for yourself why it's failing: `* * * * * /home/open-cv/run.sh >> /home/open-cv/run.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that your script is executable

```
chmod +x /home/open-cv/run.sh
```

2. Try to use a particular binary from your environment

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/py/env/bin/python /home/py/script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.